# Error opening directory in Xournal++ app : operation not permitted

Tags: mac, big-sur

I am using Mac OS Big Sur version 11.5.2

I downloaded Xournal++ from https://xournalpp.github.io/installation/macos/#installing-program

I have installed the app

Some one sent me some .xopp files they created on xournal++ app. When I saved it in downloads and try to open with the app, it says "Error opening directory (**) operation not permitted"

"System Preferences" > "Security Privacy" > "Files and Folders" or "Full Disk Access" doesn't list Xournal++.

Please let me know how can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [known issue](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp/issues/1757). Xournal++ doesn't seem to play well with the new MacOS security features.

Until the problem is fixed, you can, as a workaround, put all your Xournal files into a directory that's not guarded so vigilantly by MacOS. For example, create a folder called "Xournal files" in your user's home directory and download the file there. Xournal++ should happily open it.